# How can I call a .exe file W/unknown Path?

Tags: c#

How can I call a .exe file W/unknown Path which installed on the machine in C#?

```
Process.Start(?);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Process.Start("myExeFileName.exe");
```

You'll need to hope that the system search path includes the path where the executable lives, or that it has registered an `APPPATH`.

Comment: (You'll also need to hope that the *correct* executable will be called - a long time ago, I used an app which installed various versions of itself into various places in PATH, and couldn't figure out why I was always getting the old version)